# How to install python packages from different indexes using conda and pip?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have two indexes. One is not very reliable, the connection is often slow, it contains a copy of PyPI plus some packages that I need. The other one is actually default PyPI. I would like to create some `environment.yml` to setup my conda environment on another machine so it would not always be a pain to configure. I would like to install only packages unique to the first index and use default index for all the other packages. But my `environment.yml` makes it so all the packages are searched for and installed from the first index.

My `environment.yml` looks like this right now:

```yaml
name: test-environment
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pip=22.2.2
  - python=3.7.15
  - pip:
    - -r requirementsA.txt
    - -r requirementsB.txt
```

And `requirementsA.txt` looks like this:

```
--index-url https://pypi.org/simple
byexample==10.5.6
```

And `requirementsB.txt` like this:

```
--index-url https://pypi.mydomain.yada
some_unique_package_for_that_index==0.3
```

Then I run `conda env create -f environment.yml` and after some thinking it searches and installs all packages from my custom index! For this test example it is ok, but in my production environment I have some heavy packages like `torch` and my custom index almost always fails to install it due to connection issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your `pip.ini` file to include extra indices that are searched as well.

```
[global]
index-url = http://pypi.org/simple
extra-index-url = https://pypi.mydomain.yada/simple
trusted-host = 
    pypi.org
    pypi.mydomain.yada
```

Comment: made a `pip.ini` file in the root directory, then `conda env create -f environment.yml` and it still searched in the pypi.mydomain.yada